# Changing bar width when using stat_summary with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `stat_summary` in ggplot to plot a bar chart. I would like to change the width of the bars. Usually this is done using the `width` option. With pre-summarised data and `stat="identity` it works as expected:

```
data <- data.frame(group=rep(c("a","b"), 20), y=rnorm(40,100,50))
se <- function(x, na.rm=T) sd(x, na.rm=na.rm)/sqrt(length(x))
data2 <- cast(data, group ~ ., value="y", c(mean, se))
ggplot(data2, aes(group, mean, ymin=mean-1.96*se, ymax=mean+1.96*se)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) + geom_errorbar(width=0, size=2)
```

However, in the same plot on original data using `stat_summary`, the bars don't change width, while errorbars do:

```
ggplot(data, aes(group, y)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", width=0.5) +
 stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", geom="errorbar", width=0, size=2)
```

**Is there a way to change bar width even when using `stat_summary`?**

Since the first example works, this question obviously already has a work-around, however, I would really like to know if there is any way to do it with `stat_summary`, because I use it a lot and is often more convenient.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Congratulations on a well written first question with a reproducible example!!

Comment: I had a similar problem and discovered in the documentation for stat_summary that the width aesthetic can be defined in the fun.data function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the subject of a known issues [444](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/444) and [235](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/235)

The current solution is to pass `width` within `aes` -- this goes against the principles of `ggplot` (mapping vs setting), but at least it works....

Note that you can use `linerange` if you want the error bars without erro bars!

```
ggplot(data, aes(group, y)) + 
 stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", aes(width=0.5)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", geom="linerange",  size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks! I'll use it for the time being while the issue is being resolved.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time and now i found it. Thanks for the very useful tip.

Comment: In ggplot2_3.3.5 using width = .7 directrly without aes()

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved. `width` now also works with `stat_summary` and `geom="errorbar"`.