# ggplot: How to add a segment with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This question is related to [How to change boxplot settings when stat_summary is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363933/ggplot-how-to-change-boxplot-settings-when-stat-summary-is-used), where I managed to build nice unicolor boxplots.

However, due to the "unicolor", the median segment's colour cannot be distinguished from the rest of the box. I've managed to add a black point for the median, but I prefer to add a segment instead. Here is the code:

```
# Data
xdf2 <- data.frame(month = rep(1:6, each = 100), 
                   grp = rep(c('A','B'), 50*6))
xdf2$m <- rpois(n = nrow(xdf2),10)

# Definition of whiskers
f <- function(x) {
   r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.10, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.90))
   names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
   r
 }

# Add points outside of whiskers     
o <- function(x) {
  subset(x, x < quantile(x, probs=0.1) | quantile(x, probs=0.9) < x)
}

# Plot
ggplot(data = xdf2, aes(factor(month), m, colour = grp, fill = grp)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = f, geom="boxplot", 
               position = position_dodge(width=1), size = 2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = o, geom="point", 
               position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("indianred","orange"), labels = c("AAA", "BBB")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("indianred", "orange"), labels = c("AAA", "BBB")) +    
  theme_bw() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "median", geom = "point", 
               position = position_dodge(width = 1), col = "black", size = 4)
```

And here is the graph:

[image]

I would like to add a segment by building a function which compute the parameters for `geom="segment"`:

```
# Add function to compute segment parameters
s <- function(x,y,z) {
  x2     <- x - z
  y2     <- median(y)
  x2end  <- x + z
  y2end  <- median(y)
  # assemble the named output
  out <- c(x = x2, y = y2, xend = x2end, yend = y2end)
  names(out) <- c("x","y","xend","yend")
  out
}
```

and replace the geom="point" part with:

```
stat_summary(fun.y = s(month, m, 0.3), geom = "segment", 
             position = position_dodge(width = 1), col="black")
```

What I get is:

> Error in s(month, m, 0.3) (from #2) : object 'month' not found

If I could better understand the logic of `stat_summary`, I could solve this problem. But I find it's not easy. If somebody could help me to solve this problem with `stat_summary` and `geom = "segment"`, I would be very glad and maybe I will understand better the logic behind.

I would also appreciate alternative solutions for adding a horizontal line to mark the median.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many pieces to a boxplot that it's probably worth the effort to change the underlying ggproto object, rather than recreate outliers / whiskers / boxes / median segments piece by piece, & hope they still stack well together.

Here's the result:

```
# Data
set.seed(123)
xdf2 <- data.frame(month = rep(1:6,each=100), grp = rep(c('A','B'), 50*6))
xdf2$m <- rpois(n=nrow(xdf2),10)

p <- ggplot(data = xdf2,
            aes(factor(month), m, colour = grp, fill = grp)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "indianred", "B" = "orange"),
                     labels = c("A" = "AAA", "B" = "BBB"),
                     aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

p + 
  geom_boxplot2(position = position_dodge(width = 1), size = 2,
                qs = c(0.10, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.90),
                median.colour = "black")
```

[image: result]

Here are some more variations with different aesthetic options:

```
library(dplyr)

cowplot::plot_grid(
  p +  
    labs(subtitle = paste("quantiles = c(0.05, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.95)",
                          "median segment color = brown",
                          sep = "\n")) +
    geom_boxplot2(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 2,
                  qs = c(0.05, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.95),
                  median.colour = "brown"),

  p %+% filter(xdf2, !(month == 2 & grp == "B")) +  
    labs(subtitle = paste("some data missing",
                          "position = dodge2, preserve = single",
                          sep = "\n")) +
    geom_boxplot2(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"), size = 2,
                  qs = c(0.10, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.90),
                  median.colour = "black"),

  p %+% filter(xdf2, !(month == 2 & grp == "B")) +  
    labs(subtitle = paste("some data missing",
                          "position = dodge, preserve = single",
                          sep = "\n")) +
    geom_boxplot2(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), size = 2,
                  qs = c(0.10, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.90),
                  median.colour = "black"),

  nrow = 1
)
```

[image: variations]

Code:

```
# define stat_boxplot2() based on stat_boxplot, but with boxplot quantiles (qs) 
# added as a parameter (default values are same as original function), & 
# stat = StatBoxplot2 instead of StatBoxplot
stat_boxplot2 <- function (
  mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "boxplot", position = "dodge2", 
  ..., coef = 1.5, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
  qs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = StatBoxplot2, 
        geom = geom, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, 
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(na.rm = na.rm, 
                      coef = coef, 
                      qs = qs, ...))
}

# define StatBoxplot2 based on StatBoxplot, with compute_group function tweaked
# to use qs passed from stat_boxplot2(), & outlier definition simplified to
# include all data points beyond the range of qs values
StatBoxplot2 <- ggproto(
  "StatBoxplot2", StatBoxplot,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, width = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, coef = 1.5,
                           qs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) {
    if (!is.null(data$weight)) {
      mod <- quantreg::rq(y ~ 1, weights = weight, data = data, 
                          tau = qs)
      stats <- as.numeric(stats::coef(mod))
    }
    else {
      stats <- as.numeric(stats::quantile(data$y, qs))
    }
    names(stats) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
    iqr <- diff(stats[c(2, 4)])
    outliers <- data$y < stats[1] | data$y > stats[5] # change outlier definition

    if (length(unique(data$x)) > 1) 
      width <- diff(range(data$x)) * 0.9
    df <- as.data.frame(as.list(stats))
    df$outliers <- list(data$y[outliers])
    if (is.null(data$weight)) {
      n <- sum(!is.na(data$y))
    }
    else {
      n <- sum(data$weight[!is.na(data$y) & !is.na(data$weight)])
    }
    df$notchupper <- df$middle + 1.58 * iqr/sqrt(n)
    df$notchlower <- df$middle - 1.58 * iqr/sqrt(n)
    df$x <- if (is.factor(data$x)) 
      data$x[1]
    else mean(range(data$x))
    df$width <- width
    df$relvarwidth <- sqrt(n)
    df
  }
)

# define geom_boxplot2() based on geom_boxplot, using stat = "boxplot2" by 
# default instead of "boxplot", with a new parameter median.colour, &
# geom = GeomBoxplot2 instead of GeomBoxplot
geom_boxplot2 <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "boxplot2", position = "dodge2", 
                          ..., outlier.colour = NULL, outlier.color = NULL, outlier.fill = NULL, 
                          outlier.shape = 19, outlier.size = 1.5, outlier.stroke = 0.5, 
                          outlier.alpha = NULL, notch = FALSE, notchwidth = 0.5, varwidth = FALSE, 
                          na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, 
                          median.colour = NULL, median.color = NULL) {
  if (is.character(position)) {
    if (varwidth == TRUE) 
      position <- position_dodge2(preserve = "single")
  }
  else {
    if (identical(position$preserve, "total") & varwidth == 
        TRUE) {
      warning("Can't preserve total widths when varwidth = TRUE.", 
              call. = FALSE)
      position$preserve <- "single"
    }
  }

  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomBoxplot2, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(outlier.colour = outlier.color %||% outlier.colour, 
                      outlier.fill = outlier.fill, outlier.shape = outlier.shape, 
                      outlier.size = outlier.size, outlier.stroke = outlier.stroke, 
                      outlier.alpha = outlier.alpha, notch = notch, notchwidth = notchwidth, 
                      varwidth = varwidth, na.rm = na.rm, 
                      median.colour = median.color %||% median.colour, ...))
}

# define GeomBoxplot2 based on GeomBoxplot, with draw_group function & draw_key
# functions tweaked to use median.colour for the median segment's colour, if available
GeomBoxplot2 <- ggproto(
  "GeomBoxplot2",
  GeomBoxplot,
  draw_group = function (data, panel_params, coord, fatten = 2, outlier.colour = NULL, 
                         outlier.fill = NULL, outlier.shape = 19, outlier.size = 1.5, 
                         outlier.stroke = 0.5, outlier.alpha = NULL, notch = FALSE, 
                         notchwidth = 0.5, varwidth = FALSE, median.colour = NULL) {

    common <- data.frame(colour = data$colour, size = data$size, 
                         linetype = data$linetype, fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha), 
                         group = data$group, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    whiskers <- data.frame(x = data$x, xend = data$x,
                           y = c(data$upper, data$lower), 
                           yend = c(data$ymax, data$ymin), 
                           alpha = NA, 
                           common, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    box <- data.frame(xmin = data$xmin, xmax = data$xmax, ymin = data$lower, 
                      y = data$middle, ymax = data$upper, 
                      ynotchlower = ifelse(notch, data$notchlower, NA), 
                      ynotchupper = ifelse(notch, 
                                           data$notchupper, NA), 
                      notchwidth = notchwidth, alpha = data$alpha, 
                      common, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    if (!is.null(data$outliers) && length(data$outliers[[1]] >= 1)) {
      outliers <- data.frame(y = data$outliers[[1]], x = data$x[1], 
                             colour = outlier.colour %||% data$colour[1], fill = outlier.fill %||% 
                               data$fill[1], shape = outlier.shape %||% data$shape[1], 
                             size = outlier.size %||% data$size[1], stroke = outlier.stroke %||% 
                               data$stroke[1], fill = NA, alpha = outlier.alpha %||% 
                               data$alpha[1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      outliers_grob <- GeomPoint$draw_panel(outliers, panel_params, 
                                            coord)
    }
    else {
      outliers_grob <- NULL
    }
    if(is.null(median.colour)){
      ggplot2:::ggname(
        "geom_boxplot", 
        grobTree(outliers_grob, 
                 GeomSegment$draw_panel(whiskers, panel_params, coord), 
                 GeomCrossbar$draw_panel(box, fatten = fatten, panel_params, coord)))
    } else {
      ggplot2:::ggname(
        "geom_boxplot", 
        grobTree(outliers_grob, 
                 GeomSegment$draw_panel(whiskers, panel_params, coord), 
                 GeomCrossbar$draw_panel(box, fatten = fatten, panel_params, coord),
                 GeomSegment$draw_panel(transform(box, x = xmin, xend = xmax, yend = y,
                                                  size = size, alpha = NA,
                                                  colour = median.colour), 
                                        panel_params, 
                                        coord)))
    }
  },
  draw_key = function (data, params, size) {
    if(is.null(params$median.colour)){
      draw_key_boxplot(data, params, size)
    } else {
      grobTree(linesGrob(0.5, c(0.1, 0.25)), 
               linesGrob(0.5, c(0.75, 0.9)), 
               rectGrob(height = 0.5, width = 0.75), 
               linesGrob(c(0.125, 0.875), 0.5,
                         gp = gpar(col = params$median.colour)), 
               gp = gpar(col = data$colour, 
                         fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
                         lwd = data$size * .pt, 
                         lty = data$linetype))
    }
  }
)
```